# Most pythonic way to pass unknown amount of return values from one function as *args to another function in python

Tags: python

I am writing some Python code where the part of interest has the following setup:

- A function handle which is assigned to a function defined by the user. It must take at least one argument. Let's call it `f`
- Another function handle which is either `None` or assigned to the handle of some function define by the user. Let's call it `get_extras`. If it is not `None`, it takes no values and may return one or more values corresponding to the second and subsequent arguments of `f`. These do not need to be iterable.
- Some value that will be passed as the first argument of `f`. Let's call it `value`

The idea is that the user defines `f` to perform a calculation on the generated `value` as well as optionally incorporate some extra components generated by `get_extras`. My code as it stands is below, and I am wondering what is in face the best way to implement this. The key sticky issue seems to be you cannot use `*extras` if `g` returns one value. I could impose another restraint on the user such that single value returns must be in a tuple but that doesn't seem nice to me.

```
value = generate_value()

if self.get_extras:
    extras = self.get_extras()
    if not isinstance(extras, tuple):
        extras = (extras,)

output = self.f(value, *extras)
```

Comment: @Peterw why not make an interface correct and always return iterable, either empty, single-element or multiple-element (depending on exact problem specification?)

Comment: No worries, perhaps my way is the appropriate way to do it, the code I posted after all works so far, but you'd think there's a neater way to pipeline arguments from one function to another